# Когда появился первый orm (object relation mapping)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, ооп, orm

Подскажите, а в каком году зародилось направление orm и кто был первопроходцем? На wiki не слишком богатая статья.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего тематике сайта.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Это сайт о программировании и системном администрировании, но вот написание исторических справок о том и другом — вне тематики. Попробуйте аналогичные статьи Википедии на других языках.

Comment: Возможно это все же [Postgres](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) , хотя Кузнецов [пишет](http://citforum.ru/database/articles/ordbms10/), это Informix (в 96-м).

Comment: На американском сайте надо спрашивать. Вся история программирования пишется в америке.